# Why is there a missing method error even when the code block is never called?

Tags: java, jvm, switch-statement

I'm writing a Mad Libs program. In it, there are a variety of stories.. or at least there will be. At the moment, there's only one. But my method that chooses a story has reference to methods I haven't made yet. For some reason, this code will not compile, even though at no point am I calling the unmade methods. Why is this?

Here's the choose a story method.

```
public void chooseStory (int choice)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            story1();
            break;
        case 2:
            story2();
            break;
        case 3:
            story3();
            break;
        case 4:
            story4();
            break;
        }
```

But even if `choice` is 1, I still get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method story2() is undefined for the type MLServer
    The method story3() is undefined for the type MLServer
    The method story4() is undefined for the type MLServer

    at MLServer.chooseStory(MLServer.java:13)
    at MLApp.main(MLApp.java:31)
```

Why is the JVM evaluating code that's never hit?

Comment: It has nothing to do with "code being hit" but rather code that is not compilable.  Put in the methods. But your main problem is that you're trying to run code that won't compile -- don't do that.

Comment: it's conditional code, but since java can't tell in advance that you're not going to be calling it, it's rightfully pointing this out.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the insight. I thought since the method was called with the value of 1, it would know not to go into the other cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't know what code will be called. You might aswell upload and use the class-files from a server for example. Apart from that it would be pretty complicated (or even impossible, if user-choices are involved) to predicate which parts of the code will be accessed and which not. And the resulting byte-code would contain references to code that doesn't even exist, which would make compilation and execution pretty complicated.

Comment: I get it now. I thought, since it was in a called method and not the main method, since the method was called with the value of 1, it would know not to go into the other cases. Guess I was wrong! Thanks for the help, starting to learn JVM's quirks a bit better.